# Is there a better jQuery solution to this.form.submit();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I want to trigger the submit event of the form the current element is in. A method I know works sometimes is:

```
this.form.submit();
```

I'm wondering if there is a better solution, possibly using jQuery, as I'm not 100% sure method works in every browser.

Edit:

The situation I have is, as follows:

```
<form method="get">
    <p><label>Field Label
        <select onchange="this.form.submit();">
            <option value="blah">Blah</option>
            ....
        </select></label>
    </p>
</form>
```

I want to be able to submit the form on change of the `<select>`.

What I'm looking for is a solution that works on any field within any form without knowing the id or name on the form. `$('form:first')` and `$('form')` won't work because the form could be the third on the page. Also, I am using jQuery on the site already, so using a bit of jQuery is not a big deal.

So, is there a way to have jQuery retrieve the form the input/select/textarea is in?

Comment: The method you post has always worked for me.

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't this.form.submit() work?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
$(field).closest("form").submit();
```

For example, to handle the onchange event, you would have this:

```
$(select your fields here).change(function() {
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
});
```

If, for some reason you aren't using jQuery 1.3 or above, you can call `parents` instead of `closest`.

Comment: use closest("form") instead of parents("form"). parents() gets all the parents of the element that are forms, closest() stops ate the first form that is parent of the element

Comment: @TeKapa: Thanks. jQuery 1.3 (which added the `closest` function) came out a week after I answered the question.

Answer (score 25):

```
this.form.submit();
```

This is probably your best bet. Especially if you are not already using jQuery in your project, there is no need to add it (or any other JS library) just for this purpose.

Answer (score 5):

I have found that using jQuery the best solution is

```
$(this.form).submit()
```

Using this statement jquery plugins (e.g. [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form)) works correctly and jquery DOM traversing overhead is minimized.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to [Matthew's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418076/is-there-a-better-jquery-solution-to-this-form-submit/419111#419111) answer, I just found that you can do the following:

```
$(this).closest('form').submit();
```

Wrong: The problem with using the parent functionality is that the field needs to be immediately within the form to work (not inside tds, labels, etc).

I stand corrected: parent**s** (with an s) also works. Thxs Paolo for pointing that out.

Comment: with parent('form') what you said may be true, but with parentS('form') it should work even if it the field is inside a td, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't parents('form') return all forms that are parents of this element? That would potentially submit an outer form that you hadn't intended to submit yet.

Comment: Just came across this and want to add that you should not have forms within forms. This is invalid and won't work in IE. So using `parents("form")` is perfectly acceptable, although I don't know how efficient it is compared to `closest("form")`.

Answer (score 3):

You can always [JQuery-ize](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) your form.submit, but it may just call the same thing:

```
$("form").submit(); // probably able to affect multiple forms (good or bad)

// or you can address it by ID
$("#yourFormId").submit();
```

You can also [attach](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) functions to the submit event, but that is a different concept.

Comment: Question says he doesn't want to do this

Comment: It certainly does now. That was in the edit that occurred the day after my answer was submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Your question in somewhat confusing in that that you don't explain what you mean by "current element".

If you have multiple forms on a page with all kinds of input elements and a button of type "submit", then hitting "enter" upon filling any of it's fields will trigger submission of that form. You don't need any Javascript there.

But if you have multiple "submit" buttons on a form and no other inputs (e.g. "edit row" and/or "delete row" buttons in table), then the line you posted could be the way to do it.

Another way (no Javascript needed) could be to give different values to all your buttons (that are of type "submit"). Like this:

```
<form action="...">
    <input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="...">
    <button type="submit" name="myaction" value="edit">Edit</button>
    <button type="submit" name="myaction" value="delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

When you click a button only the form containing the button will be submitted, and only the value of the button you hit will be sent (along other input values).

Then on the server you just read the value of the variable "myaction" and decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery you can call

```
$("form:first").trigger("submit")
```

Don't know if that is much better. I think form.submit(); is pretty universal.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="get">
   <p><label>Field Label
      <select onchange="this.form.submit();">
         <option value="blah">Blah</option>
            ....
     </select>
     </label>
   </p>
    **<!-- <input name="submit" type="submit" /> // name="submit_new_name" -->**
  </form>

<!-- 

   this.form.submit == this.form.elements['submit'];

-->
```