# submit form with link while checking values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an HTML form defined as

```
<form name="writeYourAd" id="writeYourAd" method="post" action="post.php?action=preview" onsubmit="return checkContentForm(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

If I use a , it works fine. But if instead I use this:

```
<a href="#" class="mmh_orngebtn mmh_grybtn" onclick="javascript:document.writeYourAd.submit();"><span>continue</span></a>
```

It submits the form but does not run the checkContentForm function (or at least it lets me through anyways).

Why? What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to point the onclick handler to your checkContentForm function.

Or write your own submit function that includes calling checkContentForm and then submits.

Answer (score 1):

try add the function to the submit button as an onclick event

Comment: make sure you return false if any errors pop-up so it doesn't submit

Answer (score 0):

You should call `form.onsubmit()` manually, then remove it (in case if some browsers will call it on `submit()` call, because it's what they should do by spec, but most of them don't), then call form.submit()

Also take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag/645556#645556)

Answer (score 0):

it will go to your post.php page before it will perform the onsubmit function

try staying on the same page and using include in you post.php

like

```
if ($_POST[submit]){
 include "post.php";
 echo "<script>return checkContentForm(document.writeYourAd);</script>";
}
```

or you can remove the action, then send your post before or after the checkContentForm() function using ajax

```
<form name="writeYourAd" id="writeYourAd" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return SendQuery(this);" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

JavaScript:

```
function SendQuery(myForm)
{
 xmlhttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
if (xmlhttp==null)
  {
  alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
  return;
  }

var url="post.php";
url=url+"?action=preview";
thisForm = myForm;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4){
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200){
            return checkContentForm(thisForm);
        }
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  // code for IE6, IE5
  return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
return null;
}
```

Just Check for some errors.