# jQuery .submit problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-submit, onsubmit

I'm having a little problem with jQuery:
I'm having `.submit()` defined on a form, when I submit the form by clicking the submit button, the even triggers and things works smoothly, however, when I use `document.forms[0].submit()`, the event doesn't get triggered, but the form submits!! Is there any reason why? How can I overcome that?

Comment: duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's just the way it works - calling the native `.submit()` doesn't trigger the javascript event handler.

Use the jQuery `.submit()` instead:

```
$('form:first').submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

If the submit form is named like this

```
<form method="POST" id="the_waffle_form">
```

Then you can submit it by doing this.

```
$("#the_waffle_form").submit();
```

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/submit) for more great examples.

Answer (score 0):

There are some of us out here that are forced to use code from legacy systems. These systems are non-compliant, and in my case awaiting to be upgraded. But when several thousands of people are using the system, it's just not possible to go in and change code to baseline packages. So, we are forced to find workarounds. In my case, the forms do not have IDs or names, so using `document.forms[0].submit()` is one of the only options.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question!

Answer (score -1):

This may sound strange but why do you even use `document.forms[0].submit()` when you use jQuery already.

Simple (maybe stupid?) suggestion: Don't use `document.forms[0].submit()` use this instead

```
$("#hereidofyourform").submit()
```