# HTML 5 form submit handler called even if form is invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing some unit tests for an HTML 5 app that uses the HTML 5 form validation API. I've attached a `submit` event handler to the form that does some custom handling before serializing to JSON and passing it off to my server.

What I've discovered, though, is that if I initiate a jQuery `submit()` event on the form, even if it's invalid, my submit handler still gets called.

Instead, I'd expect my event handler not to have been called because the form is invalid.

I've created a JSFiddle to demonstrate (tested in Chrome 20):

http://jsfiddle.net/jonbca/SYg4h/22/

So, what gives?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this on Chrome using your fiddle. I also changed the action to an external site and it still didn't cause any problems? Also, try using `e.preventDefault()` instead of or as well as `return false;`

Comment: I don't think the form validation stuff is performed when you programatically invoke the operation.  You can call the "checkValidity()" routine yourself, but that won't do the visual validity indications. (*edit* actually I'm fairly certain that this is the case; in the fiddle, you're not even making it to the actual "submit()" method on the form DOM element; it's just the jQuery handler. You have to call "checkValidity()" yourself.)

Comment: return false does the e.preventDefault(); as well as e.stopPropagation (); (in jQuery, go read the source.) so, really return false is better in this case.

Comment: @rlemon but only so long as the intervening code doesn't throw an exception...

Comment: @Gavin you're right... I'll edit the question.

Comment: @rlemon there's a subtle difference between preventDefault and stopPropagation

Comment: @MihaiStancu you don't understand that he said that `return false` does both `.preventDefault()` AND `.stopPropagation`. Thus any answer merely suggesting `.preventDefault()` is false.

Comment: can you please check this item http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag

Comment: Seems like the implicit html5 validator in the fiddle above incorrectly checks emails like `abc@def` and is submitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggering the ".submit()" handler simply does not have anything to do with the HTML5 form validation mechanism. That mechanism is really quite independent of JavaScript, and in fact it's mostly unavailable from the DOM API.  You can explicitly call "checkValidity()" on a form element, but that just returns a boolean result and does not do any of the visual form updates that happen when the *user* clicks a "submit" form control.

It's important to keep in mind that many of the fancy HTML5 "smart markup" behaviors are designed to allow things to happen *without* the need for JavaScript.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the explanation. It seems to work with a click handler, as another poster suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering the submit button:

```
$('#submitBtn').click();
```

If you don't have one, just do a hidden one, that replicates the action.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/SYg4h/30/

Comment: Before being so trigger friendly on the downvote, maybe you'd like to add an additional comment as to what's wrong with my answer. All this negativity won't get you anywhere.

Comment: (I'm not the downvoter) I've tried that, and it works. But it doesn't test the `enter` key submission. I wanted to capture the case where the submission might occur by pressing "enter" in the last field, and figured "submit" was the best way.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a click handler on the button

```
$('#myform').submit(function (e) {
    // check for validation here
    var value = $('#foo').val();
    if (!value || value == undefined)
        $('#message').html('It did not submit');
    else
        $('#message').html("It submitted");
    return false;
});

$('#submitBtn').click(function(){
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Cqzcu/4/

Comment: Someone went downvote crazy on this question in the first 5 minutes! I'd expect the default handler for the button click would eventually trigger the submit handler anyway, so adding a click handler that just calls submit wouldn't have helped.

Comment: Wow. Lame. Possibly. It gives you an opportunity to prevent the default browser action. However, a click handler becomes necessary when the submit button isn't inside the form itself.

Comment: Ah, yesterday I learned that's not the case. You can put a `form="formId"` attribute on the button, and it will submit the specified form instead.

Comment: Interesting. There are quite a few new attributes related to the form in html 5