# Rails - How do I get my remote form to respond with JS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a page that list items. Below each item it lists out any comments for that item
(comments is a nested resource under items).

You can add a new comment in-line on the items page. When you do that, it was reloading the whole page so I want to change it to use Ajax and just use jQuery to insert the comment.

So I changed my comments/_form.html.erb to use :remote=>true

```
<%= form_for([@item,@comment], :remote=>true) do |f| %>
```

I added a format.js in my comments_controller:

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
  @comment.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
    format.html { redirect_to items_path}
  end
end
```

And created a simple comments/create.js.erb to insert the new comment onto the page:

```
$("#comments").append("<%= j(render(@comment)) %>");
```

However, when I submit a comment (even with the :remote=>true on the form) it keeps reloading the whole page/ignoring my .js file.

So I deleted format.html from the respond_to (since I don't want to use that option), but then it gives me the error **Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)**

How can I get it to stay on the current page and respond with my create.js?

Comment: Are you properly including `jquery` and `jquery_ujs` scripts on the page?

Comment: `<%= form_for([@item,@comment], :remote=> true) do |f| %>` (TRUE should not be passed as a symbol)

Comment: dogbert - I believe so because I have ajax w/ jquery working elsewhere just fine in this app.

Comment: MrYoshiji - oops, thanks! My code is correct, my post was just wrong - I just fixed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the problem:

I was submitting my comments form with javascript: `this.form.submit()`. That worked fine when I wasn't using `:remote=>true`. However for some reason breaks when I make the form `:remote=>true`.

If I use an actual submit button, the code in my question works fine.

OR if I change my JavaScript from `this.form.submit()` to using jQuery to select the form by id and submit that, that works too:

```
$("#new_comment_<%= @item.id %>").submit();
```

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question when trying to figure out something similar in 2020, using Rails 6.

I have a form created with `form_with`, which is `remote: true` by default, and I was submitting it in a Stimulus.js controller using the `submit()` function on the `HTMLFormElement`. This didn't work, but using a `<input type="submit">` button instead worked, just like in the original question.

The reason behind this is that calling `submit()` in JavaScript doesn't trigger the `onsubmit` event on the form, while clicking a `<input type="submit">` button does trigger this event ([MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)). Rails' handling of `remote: true` depends on this event being fired, so the behaviour breaks.

I used the workaround from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18072246/12288625) to submit my form in JavaScript, and the `remote: true` behaviour now works as expected.

Also, if you're using `rails-ujs`, you can use this wrapper to submit the form ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/29546#issuecomment-313981539)):

```js
form = document.querySelector('form');
Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
```

I hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Thank you for your answer @gueorgui ! I was encountering a similar issue on Rails 6.x with a `*.js` file not being called in the `respond_to` block upon form submission. The funny thing here was that it was with a form that was previously working as intended! After pulling my hair out for the past two days, simply re-including `rails-ujs` in `application.js` did the trick. Very weird!

Answer (score 2):

You should add `:format => :js` onto your form_for

And possibly update,

```
format.js { render :nothing => true }
```

Comment: bullfrog: where exactly would I add it? I tried doing: <%= form_for([@item,@comment], :remote=>true, :url=>item_comments_path(:format=>:js)) do |f| %> but that doesn't do the right thing - it takes me off of the page I want to stay on and loads a page that displays the contents of my create.js as if it were a textfile

Comment: try `<%= form_for([@item,@comment], :format => :js, :remote=>true) do |f| %>`

Comment: same thing: it takes me off of the page I want to stay on and loads a page that displays the contents of my create.js as if it were a text file. any idea why it would do that?

Comment: have you included  `jquery_ujs` ?

Comment: yep. and my new action for comments also uses ajax w/ jquery and that one works fine. can't figure out how that works but the create doesn't.

Comment: thanks for your help, see my answer below. I'll have to post another question about why my form.submit() isn't working...

Comment: Thanks bullfrog! I had the same problem and solved it by including `jquery_ujs`