# query form submit not firing while submitting by pure JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form below:

```
<button onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('myform').submit(); return false">Send Form</button>
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_value" value="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And Js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function() {
        alert('one!');
    });
    console.log($('form').length);
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
        alert('two!');
    });
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
        alert('three!');
    });
});
```

So I have two ways of form submit: by pure JS and native.
If I use native method - it's all OK, I receive three messages: "two!", "three!" and "one!".
But if I use **.submit()** there is no messages - events not firing.

jQuery version: 1.7, 1.8, 1.11

I changed call and it is example: http://jsfiddle.net/jF6fv/

Comment: On what selection are you calling `.submit()`?

Comment: I only see a native JS method, which the OP claim works.

Comment: @StephenThomas I make example http://jsfiddle.net/jF6fv/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should jQuery's $(form).submit(); not trigger onSubmit within the form tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer to your question: 
It is a duplicate of [Should jQuery's $(form).submit(); not trigger onSubmit within the form tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag) 
Basically it's not working because programmatically calling "submit" does not trigger "onsubmit" to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
a) it's no matter in this case
b) I need to use pure js for form submit. it's my task
c) You use jQuery

Comment: @indapublic I've revised my answer with further research

Comment: I cancelling my downvote. But your first answer was incorrect

Comment: @indapublic Thanks, I do apologize for assuming a bit too much at first. But as I have said, avoid downvoting simply because someone is wrong. In stackoverflow, downvoting is seen as a negative action, a punishment. Anyways, if I have managed to answer your question please check the answer accepted button :)