# Can't prevent actual submission of form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form like below

```
 <form:form action="/campaign/delete" modelAttribute="campaignDeleteForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline">
      <input type="hidden" name="brandId" value="${brandId}" />
      <input type="hidden" name="campaignId" value="${campaign.campaignId}" />
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal"><fmt:message key="daydiary.brand.delete.box.confirm.no" /></button>
      <button class="btn btn-info btn-campaign-delete"><fmt:message key="daydiary.brand.delete.box.confirm.yes" /></button>  
    </form:form>
```

my java script looks like follows

```
$("#btn-campaign-delete").click(function(){
    var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
    doAjaxPost(form);
    form.submit();
});

function doAjaxPost(form){
   form.on('submit' , function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize
    }).done(function( data ) {

    });
   });
}
```

What i see is the ajax request went to the server and now the url changes to /campaign/delete . I want to stay on the same page. is this possible?

Comment: `<form:form ` - what is that?

Comment: <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop the form form from submitting to the action URL that you have defined. Try the following :

in you form tag simply add this attribute onSubmit='return false;'

```
< form onSubmit='return false;' action="" modelAttribute="campaignDeleteForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline">
```

And from your jQuery code Where you post the data remove the submit function, keep the ajax as it is.

```
function doAjaxPost(form){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize
    }).done(function( data ) {

    });
}
```

I hope this might work.

Comment: @Saurabh Kumar In the ajax URL parameter you can pass the request to the file. You can set the path to the file in the URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay on the page don't submit it.
In other words, remove the unnecessary line:

```
form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag) shows the problem. onSubmit is not triggered when submit is called manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send ajax request to the same page you can keep your url parameter inside you AJAX request as empty string and leave your form action empty as well:

```
<form:form action="" modelAttribute="campaignDeleteForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-inline">
```

Comment: @SaurabhKumar Kindly see the comment on my reply.