# Javascript e.preventDefault(); not working on submit()

Tags: javascript

i have a problem when submitting form with javascript `submit()`

**LIVE ACTION** : https://jsfiddle.net/98sm3f3t/

**HTML** :

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
    First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    <button id="myButton" type="button">Submit form</button>
</form>
```

**JS**   :

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById("myForm").submit();

});

document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    alert("cancel submitting");

});
```

it supossed to be showing `alert()` and cancel submitting.

what's wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag

Comment: If your intent is to manually submit the form, then you don't need a handler on the `form`. Just make a function with the necessary code, and invoke it when you're ready in the handler on your `button`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Submitting a form programmatically, using JavaScript, does not trigger a submit event.

If you want your code to show an alert and not submit the form, then write it so it just shows an alert.

```
document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Your message");
});
```

Alternatively, use a *submit* button to submit the form (instead of JavaScript).

Answer (score 10):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) (emphasis added):

> [The `HTMLFormElement`: `submit()` method] is similar, but not identical to, activating a form's submit . When invoking this method directly, however:
>
> - **No `submit` event is raised. In particular, the form's `onsubmit` event handler is not run.**
> - Constraint validation is not triggered.

Instead, you can use the [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit) method, which submits a form as if the submit button had been clicked (i.e. it will run the `onsubmit` handler).

Answer (score 5):

Fix to your problem is to use input of type `submit`:

```
<button id="myButton" type="submit">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joherro3/98sm3f3t/4/

For this to work you have to remove the click event listener which is submiting your form. Listen to form submit and call `preventDefault()` is enought to prevent form to be submit.

Comment: Yes! Sorry @Quentin I added information to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I just came over this and found the correct answer.

To trigger an event programatically in JavaScript you can do something like this.

**create a submit event that bubbles up and cannot be canceled**

```
const form = document.getElementById('pform');

const evt = new Event("submit", {"bubbles":true, "cancelable":false});
// event can be dispatched from any element, not only the document
form.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<button id="myButton" type="button">Submit form</button>
```

to

```
<button id="myButton" type="submit">Submit form</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Clicking the submit button triggers the click event and submits the form normally. The normal submission gets cancelled and triggers the alert. The programmatic submission **still submits the form**.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `button type ="button"`.

Use `button type="submit".`

It will alert

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/98sm3f3t/1/)

Comment: This doesn't work (even in your live demo). Clicking the submit button triggers the click event and submits the form normally. The normal submission gets cancelled and triggers the alert. The programmatic submission **still submits the form**.