# VueJs - preventDefault() on form submission

Tags: vue.js, preventdefault

I need to submit a form programmatically, but I need it to `preventDefault` as well.

Right now I have the following:

```js
submit() {
  this.$refs.form.submit()
}
```

It is working fine, but I cannot prevent default on the submit which in the end, refreshes the page.

Comment: How are you calling the `submit()` function? Not the `$refs`, but the outer function?

Comment: I am calling it as a @click="submit". 
I know it sounds weird why I do that, but it is because I am creating a wrapper for my form, where I wan't to submit the form. 
So I have something like: <vue-form @submit="doSomething"><vue-input></vue-input><button type="submit"></button></vue-form>.
So basically I need the button to submit the form, which can be done with a slot within the form, if I can get the form to submit correctly programmatically.

Comment: And you need preventDefault because you want to "doSomething" before the form is submitted? And when this "something" is done, then you want to submit it programatically?

Answer (score 33):

### Short answer

You can add the `.prevent` modifier to the `@submit` (or any other `v-on` you're using), like this:

```html
<form @submit.prevent="myMethod">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

In the case of submitting a form, this will prevent the default behavior of refreshing the page.

### Long answer

There are several ways to modify events.

[From the Vue 3 docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#event-modifiers):

> It is a very common need to call `event.preventDefault()` or
> `event.stopPropagation()` inside event handlers. Although we can do this
> easily inside methods, it would be better if the methods can be purely
> about data logic rather than having to deal with DOM event details.
>
> To address this problem, Vue provides event modifiers for v-on. Recall
> that modifiers are directive postfixes denoted by a dot.

```html
<!-- the click event's propagation will be stopped -->
<a @click.stop="doThis"></a>

<!-- the submit event will no longer reload the page -->
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit"></form>

<!-- modifiers can be chained -->
<a @click.stop.prevent="doThat"></a>

<!-- just the modifier -->
<form @submit.prevent></form>

<!-- use capture mode when adding the event listener -->
<!-- i.e. an event targeting an inner element is handled here before being handled by that element -->
<div @click.capture="doThis">...</div>

<!-- only trigger handler if event.target is the element itself -->
<!-- i.e. not from a child element -->
<div @click.self="doThat">...</div>
```

[Another option](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/events.html#methods-in-inline-handlers):

> Sometimes we also need to access the original DOM event in an inline statement handler. You can pass it into a method using the special $event variable:

```html
<button @click="warn('Form cannot be submitted yet.', $event)">
  Submit
</button>
```

```js
// ...
methods: {
  warn: function (message, event) {
    // now we have access to the native event
    if (event) {
      event.preventDefault()
    }
    alert(message)
  }
}
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 8):

Didn't quite understand [@Armin Ayari](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51733028/6904888)'s answer, for instance why the code would have to be in the `methods` object? Anyway in Vue this is what worked for me:

```
<form ref="form" @submit.prevent="myMethod">
  <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

This blocked the page from refreshing and called `myMethod` instead.

You don't even need the `ref`. Understood this is an old question, but I found myself here after debugging, and found my form tags were simply mis-placed.

Answer (score 3):

After some proper investigation with not a single answer here being related to the original question.

I have found your solution, however it isn't **VueJS** specific, referencing this article: [Javascript e.preventDefault(); not working on submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705108/javascript-e-preventdefault-not-working-on-submit)

## Answer

Your programmatic way to execute submit `this.$refs.form.submit()` isn't correct if you want to properly `preventDefault()` or even run other functions.

You need to run `this.$refs.form.requestSubmit()`, this replicates the functionality as if you would've had a child `<button>` run the `clicked` event.

Comment: This is the correct answer to this question. Idk if other answers read the same question as as we did...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly but you can prevent the default behavior of your form like this:

```
this.$refs.form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
});
```

Maybe this can help you:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {},
  methods: {
    submit () {
      this.$refs.form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
        event.preventDefault()
      })
    },
    alert () {
      alert('hello')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <div id='app'>
    <div class="form-wrapper" @click='submit'>
      <form ref='form' @submit='alert'>
        <input type="text">
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Armin thank you!
This is where I am going.
I need the form to submit, but not to refresh the page, as it will when I just submit the form normally. 
I need this functionality because I need to emit an event, that the form has been submitted and I wan't the browser functionality of validating (ex. required).

Comment: @MaltheBjerregaardPetersen So is this answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's dona help!!

```
<form method="POST" action="http::localhost:8080/" @submit.prevent="submit_login($event)">
    // enter yours inputs here
</form>


submit_login(e) {
    if (true) {
        e.target.submit();
    },
},
```

Answer (score -1):

First, don't use preventDefault method. I will illustrate this problem on jQuery:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (event) {
  // step 1.
  // stop current action, prevent submitting 
  event.preventDefault()

  // step 2.
  // validate inputs
  // some validation code

  // step 3.
  // everything ok, submit it
  this.submit()
})
```

Where is problem with this code? When you submit this form programatically in step 3., it will be again captured and will stop at step 1. again. So, you will be never able to submit this form. Solution:

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function (event) {
  // step 1.
  // validate inputs
  // some validation code
  // this code will be always executed
  // before this form will be submitted

  // step 2.
  // then do something like this
  // continue submitting form and exit
  // this callback with returning true
  if (inputsAre === 'ok') return true
  // if inputs are not ok, program continues
  // with following line, which ends this
  // callback with false and form will be not submitted
  return false
})
```

I hope you got the point. So, I think what you need is not the preventDefault method, but return true or return false in your doSomething method called on @submit event.

Comment: Hi Vladislav.
I get where you are going, but when the form submits at the end, it will refresh the page, right?

Comment: Yes. Successful form submitting involves page refresh. So, the true solution is to use ordinary button, not the type submit, adding a @click handler, and in this handler get the formData and make post request with ajax.