# VueJS PreventDefault form action on submit not working with ref?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Currently I have something like the following code inside my `<script>`:

```
render(createElement) {
 return createElement("form", 
   {ref: "formEl" ,
     on: {submit: this.handleSubmit}
   }, 
   [ <insert create form inputs here> ]);
}

handleSubmit(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 //Other stuff that also rely on using e
}
```

If I place a submit button inside the form handleSubmit works and runs perfectly.
But if I were to do `this.$refs.formEl.submit()` HandleSubmit does not run.

I have tried a solution posted in: [VueJs 2 - preventDefault() on $refs.form.submit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51732051/vuejs-2-preventdefault-on-refs-form-submit)

By adding a event listening like so:
`this.$refs.form.addEventListener("submit", this.handleSubmit);`

Sadly this did not work.

**Edit (After Comments)**:
To elaborate on "not work":
what I found to happen is when pressing a submit button contained inside the `<form>` tags `HandleSubmit()` is actually ran twice (im assuming dude to adding a listener twice)
And I added some `console.log()` to handlesubmit and found nothing on console.

The component is made in Typescript with classes and I am pretty certain it is in the equivalent to the methods section of the component for typescript:
(inside `export default class ClassName extends Vue {}`)

What I find is that if I attach a button outside the `<form>` tag that triggers the `submit()` method on the reference the default action of updating the URL with the form contents is performed.

Comment: How exactly did it not work, any error in the console? You also mentioned "it does not run", can you confirm if this `handleSubmit` function is actually inside the `methods` section of the component?

Comment: Hi @YomS. I've updated the post to address your comment, as for errors there are none. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Would setting the `ref` attribute on the form component manually make any difference for you? Sounds like you wanted to programmatically invoke the form submission outside of the component.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working fine (without a `ref`). No doubled submission issue for me.

> The component is made in Typescript with classes and I am pretty certain it is in the equivalent to the methods section of the component for typescript: (inside `export default class ClassName extends Vue {}`)

[Yes, you're right](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Class-Style-Vue-Components).

But here's a quick demo in Javascript. (The Typescript equivalent should be close enough).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  components: {
    TheForm: {
      props: {
        prevent: Boolean
      },
      
      render(createElement) {
        return createElement("form", {
          //ref: "formEl",
          on: {
            submit: this.handleSubmit
          }
        }, this.$slots.default);
      },

      methods: {
        handleSubmit(e) {
          if (this.prevent) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          //Other stuff that also rely on using e
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Clicking on this should do nothing, since the default page-redirecting behavior is prevented.</p>
  <the-form action="/should-be-prevented" prevent>
    <input type="submit" value='Do "prevented" submission' />
  </the-form>

  <p>This should work like normal submit buttons would. And once submitted, the whole screen should go blank (showing that the page has been redirected somewhere else).</p>
  <the-form action="/should-redirect">
    <input type="submit" value='Do "normal" submission' />
  </the-form>
</div>
```

Form submission with `ref`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  components: {
    TheForm: {
      props: {
        prevent: Boolean
      },
      
      render(createElement) {
        return createElement('form', {
          on: {
            submit: this.handleSubmit
          }
        }, this.$slots.default);
      },

      methods: {
        handleSubmit(e) {
          if (this.prevent) {
            e.preventDefault();
          }
          else {
            this.$el.submit(e);
          }

          //Other stuff that also rely on using e
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
form {
  border: 2px dotted lightgray;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11"></script>

<div id="app">
  <the-form ref="form1" action="/should-be-prevented" prevent>
    This form should stay, since the default page-redirecting behavior is prevented.
  </the-form>

  <the-form ref="form2" action="/should-redirect">
    This should work like normal forms would. And once submitted, the whole screen should go blank (showing that the page has been redirected somewhere else).
  </the-form>

  <hr />
  <p>Note that these buttons are <strong>outside</strong> of the respective forms, to demonstrate programmatic form-submission trigger. </p>
  <input @click="$refs.form1.handleSubmit($event)" value='Do "prevented" submission' type="button" />
  <input @click="$refs.form2.handleSubmit($event)" value='Do "normal" submission' type="button" />
</div>
```