# Jquery bar rating system in a do-while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have many troubles to implement Ajax, Jquery, Javascript into a loop.
Currently I have a "bar rating system" that I want to use and repeat for every record in a do-while loop. But something that I can't figure out is wrong.

The part of code related to the issue bellow:

```
<?php 
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);}

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "formevalcoment")) { 
$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO tblevaluacion (idUser, idComent, intEvaluacion, dateFecha, intActivo) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['idUser'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['idComent'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['intEvaluacion'], "int"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['dateFecha'], "timestamp"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['intActivo'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_conexionproject, $conexionproject);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $conexionproject) or die(mysql_error());

$insertGoTo = "";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
?>

  <?php 
   if ($totalRows_DatosComentarios > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty

  do {
 <p class="eval_coment">Update your current evaluation</p>

    <form id="<?php echo 'form-evalcoment'.$m ?>" name="<?php echo 'form-evalcoment'.$m ?>" class="eval-form">

    <select class="bars-reversed" id="<?php echo 'bars-reversed'.$m; ?>" name="intEvaluacion" style="display:none" data-number="<?php echo $m; ?>">
       <option value="-2" style="color:red" <?php if (!(strcmp(-2, htmlentities(ObtenerEvalUsuario($row_DatosComentarios['idComent']), ENT_COMPAT, 'iso-8859-1')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Muy en desacuerdo (--)</option>
       <option value="-1" style="color:red" <?php if (!(strcmp(-1, htmlentities(ObtenerEvalUsuario($row_DatosComentarios['idComent']), ENT_COMPAT, 'iso-8859-1')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>En desacuerdo (-)</option>
       <option value="0" <?php if (!(strcmp(0, htmlentities(ObtenerEvalUsuario($row_DatosComentarios['idComent']), ENT_COMPAT, 'iso-8859-1')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>No aporta (0)</option>
       <option value="1" style="color:blue" <?php if (!(strcmp(1, htmlentities(ObtenerEvalUsuario($row_DatosComentarios['idComent']), ENT_COMPAT, 'iso-8859-1')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Deacuerdo (+)</option>
       <option value="2" style="color:blue" <?php if (!(strcmp(2, htmlentities(ObtenerEvalUsuario($row_DatosComentarios['idComent']), ENT_COMPAT, 'iso-8859-1')))) {echo "SELECTED";} ?>>Muy deacuerdo (++)</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="dateFecha" value="now()" />
    <input type="hidden" name="intActivo" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="formevalcoment" />
    <input type="hidden" name="idComent_persopoli" value="<?php echo $row_DatosComentarios_CaractPoli['idComent_persopoli']; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="idUser" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['MM_IdUser']; ?>" />
  </form>
  <?php
  $m++;
  } while ($row_DatosComentarios = mysql_fetch_assoc($DatosComentarios));
```

Before body tag ends:

```
 <script src="assets/jquery.barrating.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $('.bars-reversed').barrating({
        theme: 'bars-reversed'
      });
   });
 </script>

 <script>
 $('.eval-form').submit(function(e){
 var url = "<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>"; 
 var data = $(this).serialize(); 

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: function(data)
   {
       alert(data); // show response from the php script.
   }
  });
  e.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.bars-reversed').click(function () {
  var formNumber = $(this).attr('data-number');
  $("#form-evalcoment" + formNumber).submit();
  });
  </script>
```

Many thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Any errors in the console? What are the symptoms?

Comment: The `do{` is not closed

Comment: Please indicate what you expect and what you see. Somthing is wrong. What makes you say that?

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, That's the problem, no errors in the console. The symptoms are that is dead. It does not react.

Comment: Hi @KevinKamer the do{ is closeed. I forgot to post the end part of the "if ($totalRows_DatosComentarios > 0) { // Show if recordset not empty"

Comment: Hi @PaulH I expect to submit the ratings in a independent way for each record of the recordset. Now it's not responding at all, even more without an error message. I used the same logic that I got few weeks ago over here too. I added an dynamic id to the form, input. I think the problem is the jquery-bar-rating since it creates some new div's. So I'm not adding the id to them...

Answer (score 0):

You are currently trying to do this on click of a select element. You should try doing on change instead:

```
function submitForm(data) {
 var url = "<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>"; 

 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: data,
   success: function(data)
   {
       alert(data); // show response from the php script.
   }
  });
};

$('.bars-reversed').on('change', function () {
  var formNumber = $(this).attr('data-number');
  var data = $("#form-evalcoment" + formNumber).serialize();
  submitForm(data);
});
```

On click submits your form as soon as the element is clicked, rather than when a change is made, which is when I assume you want the form submitted.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. Now using the on('change',... it's at least reacting. But it's not sending the evaluation value of any of the records yet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help. Now using the on('change',... it's at least reacting. But it's not sending the evaluation value of any of the records yet. Should be working fine. I used the same dynamic id logic with a similar evaluation system. Which it is working fine. The difference is that this one uses Jquery. Then it's creating new div's with their own classes to display the bar rating.

Comment: You don't seem to have a form action attribute set for the forms at any rate. Maybe that is why nothing gets send?

Comment: I have this input in the form as action attribute "<input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="formevalcoment" />" and it's called with <?php echo $editFormAction; ?>. At least in my other rate system works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I think I see the problem now, your ajax on submit is the one you want to trigger, right? But that will not happen as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645555/should-jquerys-form-submit-not-trigger-onsubmit-within-the-form-tag. So that logic will need rewriting. See updated answer.

Comment: Interesting info and new Ajax function but it still happens the same, browser reacts bringing "alert(data)" but not submitted anything.

Comment: It alerts after submitting I was under the impression? Since that is on success callback. So it definitely has submitted, if above code alerts.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your last post. Basically it's doing the same with the previous Ajax modification on('change'...

Comment: I was asking if you got an alert? If you did then it submitted, because it cannot alert without a submit returning successfully with a 200. Alert is not going to be on the console, it will be an alert box on the browser.

Comment: Sorry my connection was down for a while. Yes, it was an alert box in the browser. But I'm sure that it's not sending anything to my DB

Comment: Thats a server side issue for you or your data is not as expected. The frontend works, check the network panel. See where the request goes to, and what values it sends. If the values and target is as expected, debug the backend, else update the frontend. Good luck.