# jQuery form submit handler not being envoked when callback triggers manual form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, requirejs, form-submit

I have an issue where the submit handler of my form is not being invoked when I manually trigger a submit of the form with class 'reCaptchaForm' with vanilla JavaScript as seen in the code snippets below.

I have the `onReCaptchaSuccess` callback which will manually submit the form, but when I do this the submit handler does not get invoked - which works when I submit the form natively in the browser with a `<button>` with a type of 'submit'.

In my template where the form lives:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['crmpicco/coursedetails'], function(details) {
        details.init();
    });
    function onReCaptchaSuccess(token) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("reCaptchaForm")[0].submit();
    }
</script>
```

My RequireJS module `coursedetails.js`:

```
define('crmpicco/coursedetails', [
    'jquery',
    'intl-tel-input',
    'jstz'
], function($) {
    var CourseDetails = {
        init: function() {            
            this.initPhoneNumber();
        },

        initPhoneNumber: function() {

            // ...some field cloning in here...

            originField.closest('form').submit(function() {                
                // this form submit handler is never envoked!
            });
        },
    };

    return CourseDetails;
});
```

I'm guessing i'm missing something obvious here, but I can't see why the submit handler is not being invoked here as my understanding was that this should bubble up.

**EDIT**: Okay, I have now read this which rings a bell. https://stackoverflow.com/a/645556/691505 - however it does not solve my problem of how to capture the programmatical submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I answered my own question in the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/645556/691505) above.

Essentially - The event only fires when it is activated by a user - **and does not fire when activated by code**.