# Why won't form.submit() trigger the "submit" event?

Tags: javascript, html

I am submitting my form by using JavaScript .submit() function.

```
form.submit();
```

But when I using addEventListener to capture my submit event, it wouldn't work.

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    //codes
});
```

I found out addEvenetListener function will only listen for onsubmit event instead of submit. Is there have any alternative solution to call my function when form.submit() is executed?

**ps: For some reasons I need to stay with form.submit() to submit my form instead of using submit button.**

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Comment: `form.onsubmit` and `form.addEventListener("submit", ...)` refer to the same event.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

> The form's onsubmit event handler (for example, `onsubmit="return false;"`) will not be triggered when invoking this method from Gecko-based applications. In general, it is not guaranteed to be invoked by HTML user agents.

To get around this issue, try using [`dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent):

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function () {
  console.log('invoked');
  
  return false;
});

// form.submit();
form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'));
```

```html
<form></form>
```

Comment: Just tested, form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit')); is working for me. But I am maintaining a old system and there is a lot of html files. If I change **form.submit()** to **form.dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))** for every single file, it would be a nightmare

Comment: @Owl well, if you have a good editor, you can find all occurrences of a string in all files within your project directory, say `.submit()`, and replace them all with this function... that's much preferable to overwriting native functions in JavaScript, which is another possibility, but a _very_ bad idea.

Comment: I found this article [link](http://codetheory.in/javascript-fire-onsubmit-by-calling-form-submit/), it might explained why my event listener is not working (I'm not sure it is correct or not). I will accept your solution and try to search through all of my files to replace the function T T

Comment: @Owl yes, that exactly coincides with the information I quoted from MDN in my answer. Maybe you missed that or something? The explanation is indeed correct.

Comment: With this solution, Firefox now logs a warning: `Form submission via untrusted submit event is deprecated and will be removed at a future date.`

Answer (score 8):

If you need not to [support](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlformelement_requestsubmit) older browsers (IE, Safari < 16), you can use [`requestSubmit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit).

Unlike @Patrick Roberts's solution of `dispatchEvent()`, this will also validate form's content! As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit#Usage_notes):

> submit() submits the form, but that's all it does. requestSubmit(), on the other hand, acts as if a submit button were clicked. The form's content is validated, and the form is submitted only if validation succeeds. Once the form has been submitted, the submit event is sent back to the form object.

Alternatively, if you have access to the submit button (***which I'm aware of that OP hasn't***), `btn.click()` is the best supported way since it will do form validation as well as will trigger `submit` event.

Comment: `form.requestSubmit()` works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this and then adding event listener to the submit

```
var form = $('form');
form.submit();
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
    //codes
});
```

You could use this instead

```
var form = $('form');
form.submit(function(event){
    // Do something on submit
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the event handler listen for the button click and then call `form.submit()` inside the callback.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually I want to call a generic function to perform some verification checking before my form is submitting and there is a lot of forms. So it is not a ideal solution for me to bind an onclick event on every buttons.

Comment: You could add a class to the buttons to be listened for so you'd only need a single event handler.

Point of note: this would all be easier in jQuery.

Comment: I am maintaining an old system, and there is a lot of pages of html files. If I add a class for the button one by one, it would be a nightmare for me.

Comment: That's very unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution would be more useful than the one you are trying. There could be some syntax error.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="formSubmit()"> Submit form</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function formSubmit()
{
   var form = document.getElementById('formName');
   form[0].submit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Actually I want to call a generic function to perform some verification checking before my form is submitting and there is a lot of forms. So it is not a ideal solution for me to bind an onclick event on every buttons

Answer (score 0):

dispatchEvent() doesn't trigger form action, requestSubmit is poorly supported... So my workaround is to call submit event handler, check its return value and form.submit() if it's true.

```
  const onSubmit = (event: SubmitEvent) => {
    if (!formElement.checkValidity()) {
      event.preventDefault()
      return false
    }

    return true
  }

...

  if (onSubmit(new SubmitEvent('submit'))) {
      form.submit()
  }
```