# Rails3 replace search box with select dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to replace a text_field_tag with a select in a rails3 search function?

My current search form:

```
<%= form_tag orders_path, :method => 'get', :id => "orders_search" do %>
<p><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %></p>
```

I wanted to replace with a dropdown to limit / filter my customers results. I've tried this:

```
    <%= select :search, params[:search], ([["Pending"], ["Open"], ["Closed"]]) %>
```

However this gives me a 500 error and an output in the log:

```
TypeError (expected Array (got String) for param `search'):
```

I've also tried:

```
    <%= select :search, ([["Pending"], ["Open"], ["Closed]]) %>
```

Which leads to an invalid number of arguments.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check [Select helper methods in Ruby on Rails](http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Select-helper-methods-in-Ruby-on-Rails) out.

You can probably do what you need with:

```
<%= select_tag "search", options_for_select([ "Pending", "Open", "Closed" ], params[:search]) %>
```

-- EDIT --

In order to submit form on select add following in your application.js (provided you use jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select#search").change(function(){
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });

});
```

There are already [few stack overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/418076/is-there-a-better-jquery-solution-to-this-form-submit) in regards to this.

Comment: Great, thanks!! Now all I've got to do is figure out how to fire my ajax request on select and forget the search button :) jx

Comment: That is easy. I will add an edit to above answer in few minutes