# Submitting a form via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I researched how to submit a form via javascript but, in my case, I'm creating several forms based on a collection of data. I don't know the best way to reference the form ID.

```
<c:forEach 
    var="meeting" 
    items="${response.mMeetingList}"
    begin="0"
    end="5">

    <div class="row">

        <ul class="span4 unstyled">
            <li>
                <form name="mtgDetailsForm" action="/transporter/app/meeting/read" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="meetingId" value="${meeting.meetingId} }">
                <a href="javascript: getMtgDetails()" class="row">
                    <div class="span1"><fmt:formatDate value="${meeting.startTime}" type="time" pattern="h:mm a"></fmt:formatDate></div>
                    <div class="span3">${meeting.meetingName}</div>
                </a>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</c:forEach>
```

And here's the JS method for submitting the form:

```
function getMeetingDetails( data ){
        document.mtgDetailsForm.submit();
    }
```

Obviously, this will not work because the form ID will be duplicated. What's a better approach?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Well duplicate form IDs would be invalid anyways. Is there a reason you cannot have a single form with all these UL inside of it and just submit the entire form?

Comment: Why don't you just use a `<button type="submit">` instead of that `<a>` tag?

Comment: Would you tag with the markup language you are using (jsp/asp/etc.)?

Comment: I'm using JSP. I was using a Form because that's how I read you can make a remote call using an A tag.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm not using a button because I'm wrapping 2 div tags within it and I don't want the button styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know the code you are using to generate the dynamic forms, but one approach would be to generate one id for each form, something like this:

```
 <form name="mtgDetailsForm${counter}">
```

Pass the form id by parameter to function

```
<a href="javascript: getMtgDetails('mtgDetailsForm${counter}')" class="row">
```

Get the form and submit it based in the parameter

```
function getMeetingDetails( formId ){
        document.getElementById(formId).submit();
    }
```

Also need to increment the counter inside the for loop `${counter++}`

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the `form` from `a`, [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BtqTt/)

```
function sub(e)
{
    var f = e.parentNode;

    // if using jQuery prefer this method to access `form`
    // var f = $(e).closest("form");

    f.submit();
}
```

Then

```
<a href="#" onclick="sub(this)">Submit</a>
```

Comment: This is fragile (will break if the event origin is not an immediate child). I prefer [`.closest("form").submit()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/419111/309483)

Comment: @JanusTroelsen me too, but he is not using jQuery I guess, and it would overly complicate the answer to implement it with pure js